# How to display the 2D array in Jquery in MVC ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am developing MVC application.
I am trying to pass the data from controller and trying to display using JQuery.

I create the array into Controller and pass it to Jquery using Json.

here is the array...

[image]

and here is the code of JQuery.

```
function getProductDetails(productCode, Index) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Product/getProductDetails/",
        data: { Id: productCode },

        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result)
          {


            $.each(result.StockData, function (key, Value) {
                alert(key + "+" + Value);
             });
        }
    });

}
```

I have displayed the alert for the values... 
it shows as below... Key shown perfectly but value shows as a object.

[image]

Comment: what tool or debugger do you use to show the structure of `myArray`?

Comment: Sorry ? Not getting...

Comment: If its not a circular structure you can use JSON.stringify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to `stringify` that object,

```
$.each(result.StockData, function (key, Value) {
  alert(key + "+" + JSON.stringify(Value));
});
```

According to your new request try like,

```
$.each(result.StockData, function (key, Value) {
  alert(key + "+" + (Value.Value));
});
```

Comment: it shows like ,  2+{"Key":3,Value":599) ... I em expecting like 2 + 599

Comment: @user1650894 sorry that was a typo, now try.. :)

Comment: just show your json structure.. what would JSON.stringify(Value) returned..? giv me the entire result not a sample..?